# How to print an individual field that is part of "_source" using Python with elastic search?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have very few fields in ElasticSearch and want to get individual fields from `_source`. Using the example below in a Python script gets a key error:

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch( [{'host': host_name}])
res = es.search(index="collections", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}, "from": 0, "size": 1})
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
  print(doc ["_id"], doc ["_type"], doc ["_source.collection.id"])
```

Comment: please post the error

Comment: When the script runs I get the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\ElasticGetCollectionInfo.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(doc ["_id"], doc ["_type"], doc ["_source.collection.id"])
KeyError: '_source.collection.id'

Answer (score 1):

You probably should  use `doc ["_source"]["collection"]["id"]` instead of 
`doc ["_source.collection.id"]`

Example:
`print(doc ["_id"], doc ["_type"], doc ["_source"]["collection"]["id"])`

Comment: sure np ,welcome to stack overflow :)  [do accept the answer if it helped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)